# Unable to load application properties in springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I have application related properties in my spring boot application. The strange issue is sometimes the properties load without any issues but most of the times they throw an exception.

Here is my spring boot class annotated with `@Configuration`. Tried debugging the issue but could not find any reason for this weird behavior.

```java
    @Configuration
    public class RedisConfig {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisConfig.class);

        @Value("${redisurl}")
        private String redisURL;

        @Value("${redisport}")
        private String redisPort;

        @Bean    
        public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {

            logger.info("--redisURL-" + redisURL);
            logger.info("--redisPort-" + redisPort);

            JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
            redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(redisURL);
            redisConnectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(redisPort));
            logger.info("--connected to redis--");
            return redisConnectionFactory;
        }
```

```
redisurl=cst-prd-007
redisport=6379
redispassword=
```

Any help is appreciated.

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.redis.RedisHealthIndicatorConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'redisurl' in value "${redisurl}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'redisurl' in value "${redisurl}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172)
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:834)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationB
```

Edit:

I also tried doing this. Did not work

```java
     @Autowired
        Environment env;

        @Bean
        public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {

            logger.info("--redisURL-" + redisURL);
            logger.info("--redisPort-" + redisPort);

            redisURL = env.getRequiredProperty("redis.url");
            redisPort = env.getRequiredProperty("redis.port");

            JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
            redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(redisURL);
            redisConnectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(redisPort));
            logger.info("--connected to redis--");
            return redisConnectionFactory;
        }
```

Issue solved after using the below approach

```java
    @Component
    public class RedisConf {

        @Value("${redis.url}")
        String url;

        @Value("${redis.port}")
        int port;

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return port;
        }

        public void setPort(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please share the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Are these properties set in application.properties? And when the exception is thrown can you please attach the stacktrace?

Comment: Added the stacktrace

Comment: in your code, i don't think your keys match? `redis.url` would not be injectable by `redisurl`

Comment: I am sorry i was trying multiple things so that confusion. I am using the exact name which are used in my properties file and the keys match with the annotated keys. Still i am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@Value` annotation, you can try using `Environment` from Spring Framework API.

Like this,

```java
    @Configuration
    public class RedisConfig {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisConfig.class);

    private String redisURL, redisPort;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean    
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {

        redisURL = env.getRequiredProperty("redisurl");
        redisPort = env.getRequiredProperty("redisport");

        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(redisURL);
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(redisPort));
        logger.info("--connected to redis--");
        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this it did not work. It was so mysterious to me so i posted on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved after using the below approach

```java
    @Component
    public class RedisConf {

        @Value("${redis.url}")
        String url;

        @Value("${redis.port}")
        int port;

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return port;
        }

        public void setPort(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }


    }
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties 

I'd recommend you check out the above. Not to mention spring already provides support for configurion redis via properties

Comment: @wandermonk How did you load the "Component" then in your project?